# Conversion utf to ascii in python with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I am trying to convert datas in DataFrame of unicode words into ASCII into a new column with certain character changes...

```
characterMap = {u'\u00E7': 'c', u'\u00C7' : 'C', u'\u011F' : 'g', u'\u011E' : 'G', u'\u00F6': 'o', u'\u00D6' : 'O', u'\u015F' : 's', u'\u015E' : 'S', u'\u00FC' : 'u', u'\u00DC' : 'U' , u'\u0131' : 'i', u'\u0049' : 'I', u'\u0259' : 'e', u'\u018F' : 'E'}

def convertASCII(word):
    asciiWord = ""
    word = str(word).rstrip()
    for c in word:
        if c in characterMap.keys():
            asciiWord = asciiWord + characterMap[c]
        else:
            asciiWord = asciiWord + c
    return asciiWord;

test['ascii'] = test['token'].apply(convertASCII)
```

So say the result should look something like this...

```
               token         ascii
1555757    qurbangaha    qurbangaha
379221          saylı         sayli
2456599      öhdəliyi      ohdeliyi
1128903            ki            ki
467997         ilişib        ilisib
```

However, the ASCII column is just a repetition of the token column instead of the desired result above? I have ran manually the convertASCII code on another script, it does what I want it to, but not sure what is the bug with pandas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the unicode conversion you are trying to do is standard then you can directly convert to ascii.

```
import unicodedata

test['ascii'] = test['token'].apply(lambda val: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', val).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode())
```

Example:

```
import unicodedata
data = [{'name': 'saylı'}, {'name': 'öhdəliyi'}]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
df['name'].apply(lambda val: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', val).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode())
```

output:

```
0       sayl
1    ohdliyi
```

Comment: Think you are missing an ending bracket, also may I add I have numbers as token too, not just regular characters

Comment: Thanks, added it. numbers will also work by default. It's not just for alphabets.

Comment: you have already converted the unicode to string at some point of time. Either not do it, or convert it back to unicode so decoding to `ascii` can be proper. `test['token'].apply(lambda val: val.decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: @BaoThai Generally it's a bad idea to write once own encoder/decoders like this. There is a high chance of missing out on lot of edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

I believe need [`str.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.normalize.html), but first need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `dictionary` for avoid lose characters:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'token':['qurbangaha','saylı','öhdəliyi','ki','ilişib']})
print (test)
        token
0  qurbangaha
1       saylı
2    öhdəliyi
3          ki
4      ilişib

characterMap = {u'\u00E7': 'c', u'\u00C7' : 'C', u'\u011F' : 'g', u'\u011E' : 'G', u'\u00F6': 'o', u'\u00D6' : 'O', u'\u015F' : 's', u'\u015E' : 'S', u'\u00FC' : 'u', u'\u00DC' : 'U' , u'\u0131' : 'i', u'\u0049' : 'I', u'\u0259' : 'e', u'\u018F' : 'E'}

test['ascii'] = (test['token'].astype("str")
                              .str.rstrip()
                              .replace(characterMap, regex=True)
                              .str.normalize('NFKD')
                              .str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
                              .str.decode('utf-8'))

print (test)
        token       ascii
0  qurbangaha  qurbangaha
1       saylı       sayli
2    öhdəliyi    ohdeliyi
3          ki          ki
4      ilişib      ilisib
```

If all possible values are define in `dictionary`, solution should be simplify:

```
test['ascii'] = (test['token'].astype("str")
                              .str.rstrip()
                              .replace(characterMap, regex=True))

print (test)
        token       ascii
0  qurbangaha  qurbangaha
1       saylı       sayli
2    öhdəliyi    ohdeliyi
3          ki          ki
4      ilişib      ilisib
```

Comment: Is there another decode which I do not lose characters? like `saylı` and `öhdəliyi`

Comment: Curious to why second solution does not seem to work. No changes happen, yet there is no error?

Comment: @BaoThai - I test it, do you use `python 2` or `python 3`?

Comment: Currently using python 2

Comment: @BaoThai - One idea - is possible export your sample data to pickle file and share? `df.to_pickle('sample.pkl')`? I try test it a bit, but really hard, because not sure how are encoded your real data. But obviously this kind of konversation is not easy.